# What is the best technique to determine Spatio temporal correlations?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, spatio-temporal

I have Carbon emissions data for 20 years for different regions in a country. I want to test the hypothesis that the emissions are statistically different for the regions over the 20 year period. What would be the most appropriate statistical technique in my case.

Best Regards,
Mustafa Ali

Comment: What do you mean by statistically different, (a) different in level, (b) different in rate of change, (c) peaking at a different time, (d) having a different profile over time, (e) something else?

Comment: This is a very good overview: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/179e/000df929d771a7dc16b7bd6f8c5686f93f6b.pdf